# UWP Frame backword navigation to partiular page

Tags: c#, uwp, navigation, windows-community-toolkit, uwp-navigation

My UWP app has a flat/lateral structure. The complete app is 4 pages exist side-by-side.

```
PAGE A > PAGE B > CAMERA > EDIT IMAGE

PAGE > PAGE B Normal Flow

PAGE B > CAMERA PAGE > EDIT IMAGE PAGE
```

In PageB select record from the `collection > capture Image > Edit image (add notes)` after click on save move back to Page B.

How to come back to PageB after Captured Image is edited and save.

Do we have pre-defined events that differentiate the `PageA > Page B` navigation and `EDIT IMAGE > PageB`.

When I tried `frame.goBack()` camera page is opening. want to do one more level down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to come back to PageB after Captured Image is edited and save.

For this scenario, you could remove  CAMERA page from Navigate BackStack before back to PAGE B from EDIT IMAGE. Then it will skip CamearaPage.

```
Frame.BackStack.Remove(Frame.BackStack.Where(a => a.SourcePageType == typeof(CAMERAPage)).FirstOrDefault());
```